# How to work on iWork files (especially numbers) in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, iwork

My question is simple. I generate a schedule in my app, and I want to export the schedule to a numbers file and give it to the user. I searched, but could not find how to. So is it possible? And if its, please point me the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a CSV file and open it in Numbers.app. From there on, I'm sure the user can save it as a .numbers file.

Comment: Agreed. There's no "COM" or "ALE" equivalent (I'm showing my age) to Apple's iWork. The best integration you can do is creating a file that can be opened, such as a CSV. Now ince you are tagging iOS, you have a *second* issue - files. Deep linking, iOS 11 enhancements, whatever - remember, iOS means **sandboxed**.

Comment: Thanks. I already knew about CSVs. They do not meet my needs due to the lack of cell formatting in such files.